# Vue fetch and put in data

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, frontend

I am new to vue js. I am making shopping web app.

Frontend request product list to backend server when product page created()
and It will be write to data.

This is my data()

```
  name: "Product",
  data () {
    return {
      products : []
    }
  }
```

and This is fetch() code

```
 fetch('http://test.exper.cc:3001/api/v1/'+ tag +'/@public/products',
        {"method":"GET"})
        .then(
            function(response) {

              response.json().then(function (obj) {
                   this.products = obj.data
                  }

              );
```

Backend server returns

```
[{"id": 1,"name": "상품명", "desc": "상품명 이라는 상품입니다.","image": "https://image.com/image2.png", "subproducts": [{"name": "1일", "prices": {"DEFAULT": 1000}, "desc": "해당 상품은 1일 상품 입니다.", "stock_count": 10}, {"name": "7일", "prices": {"DEFAULT": 6000}, "desc": "해당 상품은 7일 상품 입니다.", "stock_count": 12}]}, {"id": 2,"name": "상품명2", "desc": "상품명2 이라는 상품입니다.", "image": "https://image.com/image.png", "subproducts": [{"name": "1일", "prices": {"DEFAULT": 1000}, "desc": "해당 상품은 1일 상품 입니다.", "stock_count": 1}, {"name": "7일", "prices": {"DEFAULT": 6000}, "desc": "해당 상품은 7일 상품 입니다.", "stock_count": 294}, {"name": "30일", "prices": {"DEFAULT": 25000}, "desc": "해당 상품은 30일 상품 입니다.", "stock_count": 19}]}]
```

My program makes error
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdMiO.png)

I just need to put json to this.products data.
Can you help me?

I googled this issue but it don't helps me.
Sorry for my bad english ;(

Comment: Can you also list the whole method which has the fetch() ? It's even better that you list the whole <script> content to make it clear for the context to let people to investigate you problem.

Comment: Don't use `function` if you need to use `this`. Also promises are messy. They are not chained. There shouldn't be nested `then` without a good reason.

Comment: I am new to JS. It's so messy. I will try to clean my code